# How to change slider range background color using css?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I currently have a slider that I am styling with CSS. What I want is the range to change color when the thumb is slid. Similar to this picture:

[image]

How can I do this using only CSS? Below is what I have tried so far.

```
.range-slider .range-bar {
-fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: not supported - you would need to implement a custom SliderSkin. BTW, wondering where you got those selectors from? Not in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#slider ..

Comment: @kleopatra Actually possible (just about) with CSS and some magic with linear gradients...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a `linear-gradient` for the track background, and binding the point where the gradient changes to the slider's value. The basic idea would be that when, e.g., the slider's value is at 50%, the background should be defined by

```css
.slider .track {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, red 50%, -fx-base 50%, -fx-base 100%);
}
```

but the `50%` should change according to the slider's value.

So define the following in a CSS file (I introduced some extra looked-up colors to make it easier to modify the style):

```css
.slider {
    /* default track color: */
    -slider-filled-track-color: red ;
    -slider-track-color: -slider-filled-track-color ;
}

/* Make thumb same color as filled part of track */
.slider .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: -slider-filled-track-color ;
}

.slider .track {
    -fx-background-color: -slider-track-color ;
}
```

and then you can do

```
    slider.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        double percentage = (slider.getValue() - slider.getMin()) / (slider.getMax() - slider.getMin()) * 100.0 ;
        return String.format("-slider-track-color: linear-gradient(to right, -slider-filled-track-color 0%%, "
                + "-slider-filled-track-color %f%%, -fx-base %f%%, -fx-base 100%%);", 
                percentage, percentage);
    }, slider.valueProperty(), slider.minProperty(), slider.maxProperty()));
```

to bind the place where the color changes to the value of the slider.

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SliderStyleTest extends Application {

    private static final String SLIDER_STYLE_FORMAT = 
            "-slider-track-color: linear-gradient(to right, -slider-filled-track-color 0%%, "
                    + "-slider-filled-track-color %1$f%%, -fx-base %1$f%%, -fx-base 100%%);";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            double percentage = (slider.getValue() - slider.getMin()) / (slider.getMax() - slider.getMin()) * 100.0 ;
            return String.format(SLIDER_STYLE_FORMAT, percentage);
        }, slider.valueProperty(), slider.minProperty(), slider.maxProperty()));

        StackPane root = new StackPane(slider);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

where `style.css` is just the CSS file above. This gives:

[image]

Comment: You should format the string applying the US locale, otherwise the default one will be used, and on some users' machines you'll get a comma instead of a dot after formatting the double, which is not valid css and it will cause "CSS Error parsing". String.format(Locale.US, SLIDER_STYLE_FORMAT, percentage). Though, greate solution!